# Android view not updating on main thread

Tags: android, multithreading, view

I have an array of data model items in the application class. My first activity has a broadcast receiver that alters the values of items in the list (via push if you are curious).

I have two kinds of visual representation for a model item and I want to be able to update the view whenever I get a push, regardless of where I am in the application.

My solution was that every model item has an interface reference to their view classes, so when I update the model, the model tells the interfaces to update the views.

My problem is that the views do not update, and I have verified, the code is running on the main thread.

```
public interface IWidget {

    void setValue(int value);


}

public class MyView implements IWidget {

    @Override
    void setValue(int value){
    }
}

public class Model{
    int value;
    IWidget iWidget;


    public void setWidget(IWidget iWidget){
        this.iWidget = iWidget;
    }

    public void setValue(int value){
        this.value = value;
        iWidget.setValue(value);

    }
}
```

Comment: where using `MyView` class?

Comment: Different activities

Comment: Hey there, did you got the solution regarding this issue ?

Comment: Yea, I was generating a view twice on 2 fragments of viewpager, so I was not looking at the right one

Answer (score 0):

I was generating a view twice on 2 fragments of view pager, so I was not looking at the right one. The instance that was updating was the last one (not on the fragment I was initially looking on).